# Matlab: Merge same size array with NaN at different positions

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have arrays like this:

`[1 NaN NaN]`

`[NaN 2 NaN]`

`[NaN NaN 3]`

How can I merge them to

`[1 2 3]`

?

Comment: You have N arrays of length N with a single number at different positions? Or is it a matrix (sorted or unsorted)?

Comment: There are actually N matrices where each row is either filled with NaN or filled with numbers. Unsorted.

Comment: And when more than one array has a non-Nan number how do we merge them?  Or will there only ever by one non-Nan number per index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the vectors into a matrix and then compute the mean of each column discarding `NaN`'s:

```
vectors = {[1 NaN NaN], [NaN 2 NaN], [NaN NaN 3]};
result = mean(vertcat(vectors{:}), 1, 'omitnan'); % or nanmean(vertcat(vectors{:}),1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I was looking for. I think its simpler like this though:
`vectors = [[1 NaN NaN]; [NaN 2 NaN]; [NaN NaN 3]];
result = mean(vectors,'omitnan')`

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate all the matrices into a single, big matrix and then use logical indexing to take the numbers out:

```
A = [1 NaN NaN 1];
B = [NaN 2 1 NaN];
C = [3 NaN 2 3];

D = [A B C];
E = D(~isnan(D))
```

Now `E` looks like this:

```
E =

     1     1     2     1     3     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `NaN`s with zeros:

```
x = [1 NaN NaN]
y = [NaN 2 NaN]
z = [NaN NaN 3]
x(isnan(x)) = 0 
y(isnan(y)) = 0 
z(isnan(z)) = 0
x + y + z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all your matrices like so (this puts A on top of B):

```
C = [A ; B];
```

Then you can detect the cells that are not NaN:

```
D = ~isnan(C);
```

After that you can select with those logicals:

```
e = C(D);
```

This is now a vertical vector, you can make it horizontal with:

```
e = e';
```

Comment: I'm afraid `!` is not valid with Matlab. You want to use `~` instead

Comment: I tested with octave, ok will change it. Thanks.